# How to highlight only text in UILabel - IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, xib

I just want to highlight only text in `UILabel`, I have tried by giving `backgroundColor` for label, but it is highlighting the empty spaces also looks not good. So Is there any way to highlight text without resizing `UILabel`.

Please check the image, here labels are bigger than the text (center aligned)

[image]

Thanx.

Comment: You will have to use an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @MikeWeller Can you give more details...

Comment: I think you want background to be clear. set label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];Label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greenColor];

Comment: you are adding label in .xib or programatically?

Comment: @pm444 xib only, but I can control in programatically.

Comment: So you want gray color as backgroundcolor of your text not as label background color am i right?

Comment: @pm444 Yeah. Need to highlight only text.

Comment: Set label `sizeToFit` and set frame for appropriate position. After setting background color of it.

Comment: Downvotor request to you please mention the comment ?

Comment: I've answered same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41161425/1980246

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Most of the other solutions don't consider text that spans multiple lines while still only highlighting the text, and they are all pretty hacky involving extra subviews.

An iOS 6 and later solution is to use attributed strings:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *s =
     [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[s addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
          value:[UIColor greenColor]
          range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];

label.attributedText = s;
```

Comment: I have no idea about NSMutableAttributedString yet, anyhow its working fine. thanks.

Comment: I have tried the above process. It didn't work well with me. :|

http://i.imgur.com/XhuVL9q.png?1

Comment: This does not work as expected by the question: it also add background color to the empty spaces created by word wrapping. Check: [Highlight just the text in a UILabel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293873/highlight-just-the-text-in-a-uilabel?rq=1)

Comment: won't work well with multiline texts if you want to highlight just the text and not the empty spaces

Answer (score 3):

This will add a subview behind the text, with the correct size:

```
CGSize size= [[label text] sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]];
NSLog(@"%.1f | %.1f", size.width, size.height);
NSLog(@"%.1f | %.1f", label.frame.size.width, label.frame.size.height);

UIView *highlightView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
[highlightView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[self.view insertSubview:highlightView belowSubview:label];
[highlightView setCenter:label.center];
```

And don't forget: `[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];`

Comment: This won't work correctly if text is wrapping across multiple lines. This green view can only form single rectangles. If the second line only has 1 word, the entire line will be highlighted.

Comment: That's right, but if you have to support any iOS <6 and can't use `NSMutableAttributedString`, then this may be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

[MTLabel](https://github.com/Tuszy/MTLabel)

```
    MTLabel *label4 = [MTLabel labelWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 270, 250, 60) 
                                  andText:@"This label is highlighted, has a custom line height, and adjusts font size to fit inside the label."];
        [label4 setLineHeight:22];
        [label4 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30]];
        [label4 setAdjustSizeToFit:YES];
        [label4 setMinimumFontSize:15];
        [label4 setFontHighlightColor:[[UIColor orangeColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
        [self.view addSubview:label4];
```

Answer (score -3):

You can have a **UIImageView**, set its background color of your choice then place your **UIlabel** on it.
That will surely solve your problem. 
Here is Workaround code :

```
 UIImageView * imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 40)];
 [imgView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
 [self.view addSubview:imgView];


UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[label setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
label.text = @"My Label";
[imgView addSubview:label];


[label release];
[imgView release];
```

You can also achieve the same using **Interface Builder.**

Comment: Please mention reason for down voting !! So I can correct my answer.