# Fixing NSAttributedString background color on center-justified text

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm running into a strange problem with a UILabel whose text is center-justified and the attributed text has a background color...

On linebreaks, the background color is drawn from the label's edge to the first character, not just behind the characters. Is this a solvable problem - that I can make the background color appear only behind the actual text?

**Actual behavior** (arrows pointing to places that should be white):
[image]

**Desired behavior** (from Affinity Designer)
[image]

---

And for the curious, the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

NSString *textToUse = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum id malesuada diam. Ut eget odio libero. Sed urna elit, vestibulum et felis consequat, porta bibendum lorem";

NSDictionary *descriptionAttr = @{
                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor],
                                  NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor yellowColor],
                                  };
self.attrLabel.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textToUse attributes:descriptionAttr];

}
```

Comment: Since it's the same issue (but still not answered), you may want to follow this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330626/fixing-nsattributedstring-background-color-on-center-justified-text

Comment: @Larme seems you posted the link to this question.

Comment: Oops, wrong link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293873/highlight-just-the-text-in-a-uilabel

Comment: Ah, thanks! I didn't see that come up in my search. Seems like CoreText will probably be the way to go.