# NSBackgroundColorAttributeName for multiline attributed strings labels

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, multiline

[image: text overlaying a map]

I'm trying to display a map with information overlayed. To improve legibility on the map, I tried several ways (text shadows, outline text, darkening the map), but nothing really worked well – hence I tried to use a semitransparent box underneath the text.

I'm using the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName`, which – as you can see in the screenshot – works fine for single line labels. In the multiline case though, the box seems to fill a whole line, even if there are no characters above.

Is this a bug in `NSAttributedString`, `UILabel`, or my usage of it? Do you know a better approach?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing when adding a line break is essentially extending the UILabel with another line. So the outcome seen in the screenshot is only natural.

You cant solve it like this. I suggest you look into this solution: [Highlight just the text in a UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293873/highlight-just-the-text-in-a-uilabel?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I have the opposite problem ... which is how to Force it to fill in the line!

In your case - all you need to do is to:

map_name.addAttribute(
            NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
            value: nil,
            range: nsRange_of_line_feed_char)

for the position of each end-of-line.