# Setting attributedstring to label with backgroundcolor

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, background-color

I have two lined Label and setting the backgroundColor with an attributedString.

```
NSString *string = @"This is a UILAbel with two lines";

NSMutableAttributedString *mutableString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:
                                            string];

[mutableString setAttributes:@{NSBackgroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor redColor]} range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
```

If the text makes a line break it fills the backgroundColor to the right border and in the second line it stops at the last character.

But I want the backgroundcolor in the first line just set to the last character too.

[image: Pic example]

Comment: Can you show the image of your problem or what you want.

Comment: How did you get the right pic?

Comment: you are setting the background color to red ... looks pretty orange to me :p

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSBackgroundColorAttributeName for multiline attributed strings labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35455160/nsbackgroundcolorattributename-for-multiline-attributed-strings-labels)

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31293873/highlight-just-the-text-in-a-uilabel?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `backgroundColor` property is applied to the entire rect representing the label.

To resolve this you need to dynamically adjust your `UILabel`'s frame depending on its content, in order to achieve the desired effect.

There is a method on `UILabel` called `sizeToFit`; try calling it.

Although I recommend you use autolayout and let the label resize itself based on constraints.